# Assembly addq clarification

Tags: assembly

[image]I'm reviewing a worksheet for a machine architecture exam and I wanted a clarification on the answer my instructor provided. He's had a couple typos on previous worksheets so I wanted to make sure he was correct here. Take a look at the above picture and notice that he says the destination after the instruction would be 0x100 and the value would be 0x100, but wouldn't the correct answer be destination: 0x100 (value of %rax because of parentheses) and 0x1 (value of %rcx)? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: fixing the picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `addq a,b` instruction *adds* the contents of `a` to `b`. So if `rcx = 0x1`, `rax = 0x100` and we have `0xff` at address `0x100`, then `add %rcx,(%rax)` adds `0x1` in `rcx` to `0xff` at address `0x100`, yielding `0x100` at address `0x100` as the worksheet correctly indicates.

Your intuition would be correct if the instruction was `movq` instead of `addq` as `movq` just overwrites a memory location or register instead of adding to it.